# delete objects from an array using filter - useState

Tags: reactjs, filter, use-state

I'm trying to delete the object from an array using **.filter()** but it seems that it's not working correctly. The method I'm trying to do it is right and it displays the id of the element correctly but not deleting it finally.

**App.jsx**

```
// Adding activity names handler
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
const [activities, setName] = useState([
    { id: 0, name: 'Feel free to add, edit and delete!' }
]);
const handleSetName = () => {
    const activity = {
        id: Math.random() * 10000,
        name: value
    };
    if (activity.name.length >= 3) {
        var names = activities.concat(activity)
    }
    setName(names);
};

// IMPORTANT SECTION -----------------------------------------------------
const [filteredActivityNames, delActivity] = useState([]);

const handleDelActivity = id => {

    const filteredActivityNames = [...activities];

    const names = filteredActivityNames.filter(name => name.id !== id);

    delActivity(names);
    console.log(id);
};
//  ----------------------------------------------------------------------

// Activity Component
const activityComponent = activities.map(activity => (
    <Activity
        key={activity.id}
        activityName={activity.name}
        deleteActivity={() => handleDelActivity(activity.id)}
    />
))

return (
  <section>
    <input value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}>
    <button onClick={handleAddActivity}>Add</button>
  </section>
  {activityComponent}
);
```

**Activity.jsx**

```
export const Activity = ({ activityName, deleteActivity }) => {
    return(
        <section>
            <h3>{activityName} <span onClick={deleteActivity}> Delete </span> </h3>
        </section>
    )
};
```

Comment: "The method I'm trying to do it is right" then what's the problem?

Comment: @Dexygen I wish I could know.

Comment: You've mixed up your state, carefully check them back would solve the issue.

Comment: What is the need for`const [filteredActivityNames, delActivity] = useState([]);`? You need to get rid of it and call `setNames(names)`instead of `delActivity(names)`.

Comment: When you say "not deleting it finally" how exactly do you check? How are you adding activities? Could you show `handleAddActivity()` code?

upon deletion, in `handleDelActivity()` you set `filteredActivityNames`. So after deletion you should have your filtered array in  `filteredActivityNames`.

The variable names you use are a bit confusing. Idiomatic way for `useState()` hook is to name variables like `[activities, setActivities]`, `[filteredActivityNames, setFilteredActivityNames]` etc. as they operate on same state object. One to read it, one to update.

Comment: @palindrom wow that was strange, why don't we create a new func for it, and only uses ``setName``?

Answer (score 0):

You've mixed up your state. Here's a small snippet that demonstrates what you're looking for:

```js
const _items = [{
    id: 1,
    label: 'Item 1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: 'Item 2'
  }
]

function ItemsDisplay() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(_items)


  return items.map(item => {
    const {
      id,
      label
    } = item


    const handleDelete = () => {
      const newItems = items.filter(item => item.id !== id)
      setItems(newItems)

    }

    return ( 
    <div key={id} onClick={handleDelete}>{label}</div>
    )
  })

}

const reactElement = documment.getElementById('react-app')
ReactDOM.render( < ItemsDisplay / > , reactElement)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id='react-app' />
</body>
```